# How to loop through uneven blocks of data

Tags: excel, vba

So basically I'm dealing with a sheet of data, up to around 200,000 rows. The data is formatted somewhat as it's shown below (fake data). I'm trying to analyze each cycle to make sure that certain temperature and pressure ranges have been hit for each cycle (e.g temp is within 120-130 for any given cycle).

```
cycle    temperature    pressure 
  1           120          321
  1           121          332
  1           122          323
  2           123          334
  2           124          326
  3           125          337
  3           126          328
  3           127          339
  3           128          320
  4           129          334
```

I'm fairly confident in being able to use some if statements to see if each temp/pressure has been reached, but that part that's giving me trouble is being able to break it up into being able to analyze cycle by cycle (e.g. cycle 1 is within range, cycle 2 is within range). This would be fairly straightforward if the cycles were the same length, but they tend to vary by 1 or 2 values normally.

My current idea has been to look at the first cycle value, and then loop through the rows. If the cycle value of each row is equal to the desired value (starting at cycle 1), then the if statements that I want are evaluated. If we reach cycle 2, then we increment var so it's equal to cycle 2.

```
var = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Data").Range("A2")
For i = 2 To lastRow

    If ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Data").Cells(i, 1) = var Then
        'various if statements go here
    Else
        var = var + 1
    End If
next i
```

Now this has many issues, one being that the first value of each new cycle is skipped. But the main issue is that the ability to evaluate 'cycle by cycle' is completely ignored.

Mostly just want some help in how to think about seperating this into sections by cycle. My intuition tells me nested for loops, but I'm unsure how I'd be able to say "this is a new cycle, go to the next loop".

Comment: Is your data sorted by `cycle` ?

Comment: As Tim asked... 
If the data is sorted by Cycle then you could have variables to keep min/max of temperature/pressure, or whatever your needs are.  Then as soon as a new cycle is reached do whatever output you want and reset the variables.

Comment: Yes. The data is actually time series data, with each cycle being something like 5 seconds. But due to some weird things with when the cycle starts (1:00:10pm vs 1:00:00pm), we get the uneven cycles.

Comment: With 200,000 rows you will want to use a Variant Array approach.  Any solution that loops through the range will be very slow.

Comment: @chrisneilsen I figured that for loops would be slow (currently taking about 10 seconds for a 100,000 row one, not great, not horrible). Do you have any guidance on where to start with variant arrays in this context?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to do something like this (assuming ColA is sorted by `cycle` and has no empty cells)

```
Dim c as range, i as long

Set c = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Data").Range("A2")

Do While c.Value <> ""
    i = application.Countif(c.parent.columns(1),c.value)

    'Process i rows of data


    Set c = c.offset(i, 0) '<< start of next block
Loop
```

Comment: This seems to be working as expected so far. I'll keep on testing and let you know if I find any issues. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Here's a function that you can adjust as needed. It takes the data range as an input, finds all cycles where the values fall outside of the range, and returns a collection of bad cycle "title numbers". Those could be put into another range, printed in a message box, or treated in some other way.

```
Public Function findBadCycles(rngRangeToCheck As Range) As Collection

    Dim dblMinTemp As Double
    Dim dblMaxTemp As Double
    Dim dblMinPress As Double
    Dim dblMaxPress As Double

    dblMinTemp = 120
    dblMaxTemp = 130
    dblMinPress = 320
    dblMaxPress = 340

    Dim colBadCycles As Collection
    Set colBadCycles = New Collection

    Dim i As Long
    For i = 2 To rngRangeToCheck.Rows

        If rngRangeToCheck.Cells(i, 2) < dblMinTemp Or rngRangeToCheck.Cells(i, 2) > dblMaxTemp Then
            colBadCycles.Add rngRangeToCheck.Cells(i, 1).Value
        elseif (rngRangeToCheck.Cells(i, 3) < dblMinPress) Or (rngRangeToCheck.Cells(i, 3) > dblMaxPress):
            colBadCycles.Add rngRangeToCheck.Cells(i, 1).Value
        End If

    Next i

    Set findBadCycles = colBadCycles

End Function
```

Comment: Ooh, this is some functionality that would be really needed. I'll see if I can somehow add this onto Tim's answer.

Comment: @cybernetic.nomad Good catch, thanks. Threw that together quickly, so there might be other issues too...

Answer (score 0):

Using a `Variant Array` approach will be much faster for 200,000 rows

A simple for loop over the array, identifying first and last line of each cycle, then a loop over that cycle to process the data will do.

Somthing like this

I've included an example of how you might process the data: return the Min, Max, Avg and Population Standard Deviation of Temp and Press, placed in the row next to the first entry of each Cycle
(as you don't say what your actual processing is, treat this as a template and update to suit your needs)

On my hardware, runs in 1.7s on a random set of data, 200,000 rows

```
Sub Demo()
    Dim rngDat As Range
    Dim rngRes As Range
    Dim dat As Variant
    Dim res As Variant
    Dim FirstOfCycle As Long
    Dim LastOfCycle As Long
    Dim Cycle As Long
    Dim i As Long, j As Long

    Set rngDat = Range(Cells(2, 3), Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp))
    'Example: set return range to 4 columns next to data
    Set rngRes = rngDat.Columns(rngDat.Columns.Count + 1).Resize(, 8)
    dat = rngDat.Value2
    rngRes.ClearContents
    res = rngRes.Value2

    FirstOfCycle = 1
    For i = 1 To UBound(dat, 1) - 1
        If dat(i + 1, 1) <> dat(i, 1) Then
            LastOfCycle = i
            Cycle = dat(i, 1)
            ProcessCycle dat, res, FirstOfCycle, LastOfCycle
            FirstOfCycle = i + 1
        End If
    Next
    If dat(i, 1) = dat(FirstOfCycle, 1) Then
        ProcessCycle dat, res, FirstOfCycle, i
    Else
        ProcessCycle dat, res, i, i
    End If


    rngRes.Value = res

End Sub

Private Sub ProcessCycle(dat As Variant, result As Variant, FirstOfCycle As Long, LastOfCycle As Long)
    Dim i As Long
    Dim MnT As Double, MxT As Double
    Dim AvgT As Double, SdT As Double
    Dim SumT As Double, SumT2 As Double
    Dim MnP As Double, MxP As Double
    Dim AvgP As Double, SdP As Double
    Dim SumP As Double, SumP2 As Double

    MnT = dat(FirstOfCycle, 2)
    MxT = dat(FirstOfCycle, 2)
    MnP = dat(FirstOfCycle, 3)
    MxP = dat(FirstOfCycle, 3)
    For i = FirstOfCycle To LastOfCycle
        If dat(i, 2) < MnT Then MnT = dat(i, 2)
        If dat(i, 2) > MxT Then MxT = dat(i, 2)
        If dat(i, 3) < MnP Then MnP = dat(i, 3)
        If dat(i, 3) > MxP Then MxP = dat(i, 3)
        SumT = SumT + dat(i, 2)
        SumT2 = SumT2 + dat(i, 2) ^ 2
        SumP = SumP + dat(i, 3)
        SumP2 = SumP2 + dat(i, 3) ^ 2
    Next
    result(FirstOfCycle, 1) = MnT
    result(FirstOfCycle, 2) = MxT
    result(FirstOfCycle, 3) = SumT / (LastOfCycle - FirstOfCycle + 1)
    result(FirstOfCycle, 4) = Sqr(SumT2 / (LastOfCycle - FirstOfCycle + 1) - result(FirstOfCycle, 3) ^ 2)

    result(FirstOfCycle, 5) = MnP
    result(FirstOfCycle, 6) = MxP
    result(FirstOfCycle, 7) = SumP / (LastOfCycle - FirstOfCycle + 1)
    result(FirstOfCycle, 8) = Sqr(SumP2 / (LastOfCycle - FirstOfCycle + 1) - result(FirstOfCycle, 7) ^ 2)
End Sub
```